# Await socket Response

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, socket, async-await, socket.io

I wrote this to make the "callback hell" more manageable on the part of the coder when using Socket IO, so that there wasn't really any callback hell to go with, just a simple await.

This should work with any socket implementation, so long as it has `socket.on`, `socket.emit`, and `socket.removeListener`.

```
function emit_and_wait(socket, emit, data, wait_key, max_wait = 1000, error_on_timeout = true) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        let responded = false,
             callback,
             removed = false;
        if(!socket) {
            reject("Socket supplied is not valid.")
        } else if(socket.disconnected) {
            reject("Socket is disconnected");
        }
        let timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            if(!responded) {
                if(error_on_timeout) {
                    reject("Socket timeout");
                } else {
                    resolve(null);
                }
                responded = true;
                if(!removed) {
                    socket.removeListener(wait_key, callback);
                    removed = true;
                }
            }
        }, max_wait)
        callback = function(data) {
            if(!removed) {
                socket.removeListener(wait_key, callback);
            }
            if(!responded) {
                resolve(data);
                clearTimeout(timeout);
            }
        }
        socket.on(wait_key, callback);
        socket.emit(emit, data)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few flags (`removed`, `responded`) which are almost equivalent and possibly useless. `removeListener()` won't cause any error if listener has been already removed then `removed` is unnecessary. After you called `removeListener()` your callback won't be called then also `responded` (which BTW is a misleading name) is unnecessary. Also, `setTimeout()` won't call its callback twice then again `responded` isn't necessary.

Use `const` instead of `let` whenever possible and declare your variables (usually one per line) when you initialize them. In (untested) code:

```
if (!socket) {
    reject("Socket supplied is not valid.");
    return;
}

if (socket.disconnected) {
    reject("Socket is disconnected");
    return;
}

const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
   socket.removeListener(wait_key, callback);

   if (error_on_timeout) {
       reject("Socket timeout");
   } else {
       resolve(null);
   }
}, max_wait)

const callback = (data) => {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    socket.removeListener(wait_key, callback);
    resolve(data);
};

socket.on(wait_key, callback);
socket.emit(emit, data)
```

Few more notes: `resolve()` and `reject()` won't stop execution then you need to add the proper `return`. Use semicolon consistently: someone prefers to avoid semicolon as much as possible, pick a style and use it consistently.